# Refresh IContributorManager when underlying IAction contribution item gets updated

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a `IContributionManager...` which gets passed into a class as a constructor argument. To each of them we add a custom defined `IAction` which has a menu creator set on it (`setMenuCreator()`). The menu creator is custom defined and implements `IMenuCreator`.

Now every time the view changes I have a method which gets called. Within this method, I need my custom `IAction` to return different menu items depending on the view type.

However, I can't seem to update the `IContributionManager` as the view changes and it simply shows the menu with items which were contained in the menu of the menu creator of the custom `IAction` when it was first constructed.

I have tried to reset the menu creator on the action every time view changes, removed the action and re-added it and tried `IContributionManager#update(true)` but none of them have worked. Any suggestions/recommendations? We're on `Java 7` if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We removed the action from the contribution manager and re-created the action every time the view was refreshed. That helped in refreshing the view with the latest menu items.